# Using external class for Facebook Graph Api

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering. Is it possible to create an external class just to initialize the API then use functions to call the different items? Like a shortcut to using the API without all the nitty gritty stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The folks at bigspaceship published a few classes for this on their Github account: http://www.bigspaceship.com/blog/labs/bss-classes-flash-and-the-fb-graph/ - good stuff (check out the rest of their classes too)